# add two strings to two dimensional list

Tags: c#

i want to add in two set of strings to one list

i receive error that i cant use add

```
        List<List<String>> lastmodified1 = new List<List<String>>();
        lastmodified1.Add(new List<String>());

        foreach (string filenamelocal in files)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(filenamelocal);
            lastmodified1[0][1].Add(Convert.ToString(filenamelocal));
            lastmodified1[0][0].Add(Convert.ToString(File.GetLastAccessTime(filenamelocal)));

        }
```

Comment: `lastmodified1[0][1]` is not a list. It is a `System.String`. That's why you are receiving the error.

Comment: when you say `lastmodified1[0][0]` you are accessing the first string index of the first list in the 2nd dimension

Answer (score 1):

you target the list with the first index

```
        lastmodified1[0].Add(Convert.ToString(filenamelocal));
        lastmodified1[0].Add(Convert.ToString(File.GetLastAccessTime(filenamelocal)));
```

with the index [0] you are target the list, because the first List is implicit.
so with

```
    lastmodified1[0].Add(Convert.ToString(filenamelocal)); //this is accessing to the List inside the First list
```

you are accesing to the second List inside from the first List.
with the second index you're accessing to the value of the second list, in this case String, and you can get the method add because strings dont have

```
    lastmodified1[0][0] //this access to string value
```

Comment: hi and if i want that the list will be in two columns how do i do that?

Comment: it's many ways to do that, you can add other list, or better you can make it a array and access it like columns, with `.ToArray()` @ShayRahamim or what u mean with columns?

Comment: row colomn[0] colomn[1] Type
[0] "C:\\projects\\holon\\Database16.mdb" "24/04/2019 08:16:38" string
[1] "C:\\projects\\holon\\Database5.mdb" "28/04/2019 19:07:40" string
[2] "C:\\projects\\holon\\Database6.mdb" "28/04/2019 19:07:55" string

Comment: you wana make it dataset?? like a sql table?? @ShayRahamim

Comment: @ShayRahamim that is more work, you need to create DataTable, and add the columns that you want to use, after you need to insert the data in rows, this link maybe helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695262/how-to-convert-nested-list-to-dataset-in-c-sharp

Comment: cant i do it with nested for loop like?  for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {

                Array.Copy(files, lastmodified[i,0], i);
            }

Comment: @ShayRahamim yes, you can. You can create the table in many ways